# Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor/session'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?

Tags: node.js, session, meteor, npm

Please I did not know what went wrong in meteor app I'm developing that caused the display of this error at the console:

Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor/session'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?

I have done npm install, and npm init from my project directory yet the error persisted.

Thanks for your anticipated assistance.

Comment: It probably would help to list your node and npm versions.

Comment: The node version is v4.2.6 and npm version is 2.14.12. Thanks

Comment: You are not supposed to be calling npm init or npm install directly. Did you create your app like this tutorial? https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Blaze and not React. Yes I created my app in line with Blaze version of the tutorial.

Comment: I first noticed this error when I imported meteor/session i.e. import { Session } from 'meteor/session'; on top of .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 'meteor' from your Session import statement:

```
import { Session } from 'session'
```

Comment: I used 'import { Session } from 'meteor/session';' instead.

Comment: @Aika How is that different from what was giving you the error?

Comment: I guess, yours excluded the meteor directory in the import statement.

Comment: @Aika Well, yes, but did that fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot it did. I had to do

Comment: I meant that I used 'meteor npm install --save session' to clear that error. However, I could not reference a template in an Template events code successfully. I got this error message on the console; Error: Cannot find module './LoginModel.html'.

Comment: @Aika I answered your original question, apparently to your satisfaction. This is becoming a running debugging session, however.